# Why do I get a "not defined" error for a function declared into a jQuery ready event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a common function JavaScript file which holds the below code:

```
// js/common_functions.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showLoader() {
        if ($("#loading").length > 0) {
            $("#loading").removeClass("hideElement");
        }
    }
});
```

Now, I have included this file in a PHP one and I am using it like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         showLoader();
     });
</script>
```

File inclusion is working fine and according to me, `showLoader()` function should be called, but it is not working and I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: showLoader is not defined
```

Comment: I may get negative points for this question, but I will keep this on server which may be helpful for some one else.

Comment: Maybe you can find a better title ? But it's not easy :)

Comment: Suggest me Hugeen, I will change right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function declaration is inside another function, so it scoped to that function and not available outside it.

Don't do that.

Using a `ready` event handler there is *entirely pointless* because "defining a function" (the only thing you are doing inside it) has absolutely no dependency on DOM elements being available.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, it is working fine. This was a really silly mistake, Thanks for correcting and pointing the way.

Comment: you just need to define outside of ready function. it will surely works